# Make bash alias that allows autocomplete

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete

Is it possible to make a bash alias that will offer autocomplete (similar to hitting Tab)

What I have so far (with edits thanks to @chepner):

```
#changes directory to appropriate repo
repo() {
    cd ~/Desktop/_REPOS/$1
}
```

My Goal:

If the subdirectories in `_REPOS` were:

```
misc
hello
linux
```

and I typed `repo m` I would like it to autocomplete to `repo misc`

Comment: If you want a command named `repo`, just name your function `repo`.

Answer (score 0):

source https://gist.github.com/morris-stock/0f6e14ac1878f487bcc9c26f5fab8515

then define `repo` like this:

```
__shk_cd_baseon_complete repo ~/Desktop/_REPOS
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the [bash-completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion) project for some examples. Nice thing is that bash completion is all written in bash.